# Adding subreports to main report from multilistbox Access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, subreport

I am using a Microsoft Access 2010 (64 bit) database.

I have a form "MainDatafrm with a Multiselect list box "ReportList" and a button "cmd1".

I have a main unbound report "Signedletter".

And I have 7 unbound reports

```
Person1, Company1, Company2, Company3, Partner1, Partner2, Partner3
```

All of the above 7 reports have labels that always have data in them and that's it (they are signed, Date, and depending on which report a label that says the reportName all of these are in the reportHeader section).

I would like to pick which reports to add to my main report from my multiselect list box and not have the subreports keep repeating themselves. I can change the format of any of the reports

So far I now have some code that filters a query and debugs.prints 'Person1','Company1','Partner1' when I have selected them but I have no idea how to convey that to the report to show/hide the reports

Comment: OK, so what have you tried, and where did you run into trouble? All you did was tell everyone what you want. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Yes sorry I have lost track of just what I have tried over the last week. So far I  now have some code that filters a query and debugs.prints 'Person1','Company1','Partner1' when I have selected them but I have no idea how to convey that to the report to show/hide the reports

Comment: You want to dynamically set visibility of subreport(s)? Put code in OnFormat event of report section containing subreports. Keep in mind, subreports still occupy space even when not visible.

Comment: Yes I have put them in their own report headers and thought I could show or hide the header but I dont know how to get the debugs.prints 'Person1','Company1','Partner1' to on header format Headers are named after the subreport

Comment: I dont know how to put my code in anyother way I clicked the code button and it says put your code here and when I did it did not do anything

Comment: I got it after hours every day for a week I got what I needed